# In JQuery, How can I show calendar when someone clicks on an image?

Tags: jquery, calendar, uidatepicker

I want to load uidatepicker (jQuery) when someone clicks on an image. Right now, uidatepicker is attached to an input field: ( and it is working fine too)

$('#selected_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'M d, yy' }); $('#selected_date').click( function() { $('#selected_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'M d, yy' }); });

How can I show calendar when someone clicks on an image?

Comment: One way to do is  to `focus` the input on mouseclick event of the image and hence, calendar would be loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Assign the class `selected_date` to your **image(s)** and use code:

```
$('.selected_date').datepicker({..........});
```

Now the date picker will be triggered on the element (image in your case) that has class `selected_date`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good example of this on the jquery ui site, complete with source code:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Answer (score 1):

The following will place a small 'calendar' image next to the input textbox...when the image is clicked the uidatepicker will appear...

```
$('ReferenceToTextBoxHere').datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: './images/Calendar.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true        
 });
```

where the "buttonImage" property is a path to the image u want to show to be clicked on

Comment: The image cannot be part of the input box as it is far from it and using any hack or workaround would affect the overall structure.

Comment: My answer is related to the example on the jquery-ui site(and referenced in another answer to your question): http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger , this may not be what your looking for however